# Homomorphism into a union of $R$-algebras.

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, hom-functor

All rings/algebras appearing in this question are assumed to be commutative with unity and noetherian.

Let $R$ be a ring, let $A, B$ be $R$-algebras, and let $(B_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of sub-$R$-algebras of $B$ such that $B = \bigcup_{i\in I} B_i$. I recently came across the following (apparently trivial) claim:
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{R-\mathrm{alg}}(A,B) \cong \bigcup_{i\in I} \mathrm{Hom}_{R-\mathrm{alg}}(A,B_i),$$
where $\cong$ denotes an isomorphism of sets, i.e., a bijection.

Now I wonder whether this is actually true (and if yes, how to prove it). I guess that it could be related to the fact that the $\mathrm{Hom}$-functor preserves limits in both its arguments, but I do not see which "kind" of limit I should consider here.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It’s not true. You need to assume something; for instance, that $A$ is finitely generated as an $R$-algebra and the $B_i$ form a directed family, or something like that.

Comment: $R{-}\mathrm{alg}$ (in lowercase) is often used to denote the category of $R$-algebras which are finitely generated as $R$-modules. More than this is needed though, exhibited by tkf's counterexample with $\mathbb{R}$ replaced by $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (so that each $B_x$ is finite-dimensional as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space).

Comment: @diracdeltafunk But then $B$ would be infinite dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Perhaps better to use $A=B=\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Comment: Ah good point, thanks!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk actually my example was no better - if $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ are transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ then my example is infinite dimensional as an $R$ module.  On the other hand if they are algebraic, then $B$ is a field and the primitive element theorem means that $B_{x+\lambda y}=B$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What about $A = B = \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,xy)$? This is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra which is not generated as a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra by any of its elements.

Comment: Yes that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{Q}$, and $A=B=\mathbb{R}$.  Let $I=\mathbb{R}$ and for $x\in I$ let $$B_x=\mathbb{Q}[x].$$

Then $\mathbb{R}$ is commutative, Noetherian and has unity. Also $B=\bigcup_{x\in I} B_x$. However $1_\mathbb{R}$ is not in $$\bigcup_{x\in I} \mathrm{Hom}_{R-\mathrm{alg}}(A,B_x).$$

Comment: Thank you! I also just realized that one may simply choose $A = B$ and consider the identity map $A \to B$. If the decomposition $B = \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i$ is non-trivial (as in your example), then this yields a counterexample.

Comment: Also good to note here that $\text{Hom}_R(A,B_i) = \varnothing$ for all $i \in I$, so there can't be any bijection $\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B) \cong \bigcup_{i\in I} \mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B_i)$ whatsoever.

Comment: Can you explain please why $1_\mathbb{R} \notin \bigcup_{x\in I} \mathrm{Hom}_{R-\mathrm{alg}}(A,B_x)$ ?

Comment: Any $R$-algebra homomorphism $A \to B_x$ is, in particular, an $R$-module homomorphism. Recall that $R = \mathbb{Q}$, $A = \mathbb{R}$, $B_x = \mathbb{Q}[x]$; we see that $\dim_R(A) = 2^{\aleph_0}$ while $\dim_R(B_x) \leq \aleph_0$. Therefore, every $R$-algebra homomorphism $A \to B_x$ is not injective. But $A$ is a field, so every ring homomorphism from $A$ is injective. We conclude that there are no $R$-algebra homomorphisms from $A$ to $B_x$ for any $x$, so this union of Hom-sets is actually empty.

Comment: @mathvision The best reason is the one pointed out by diracdeltafunk (e.g. the RHS is empty).    I just noted that $1_\mathbb{R}$ cannot be in $ \mathrm{Hom}_{R-\mathrm{alg}}(A,B_x)$ for any $x$, as any $y\notin \mathbb{Q}[x]$ does not map to itself under a homomorphism in $ \mathrm{Hom}_{R-\mathrm{alg}}(A,B_x)$ (or indeed any map of sets $A\to B_x$).